Visual Studio 2022 and .Net 8.0
Why does my Visual Studio Professional not show the target platform .Net 8.0?
Environment:
Visual Studio Professional 2022 Version 17.10.2
Run latest updates for Visual Studio.
Install runtime and SDK for .Net 8.0.
Expect, that the Visual Studio shows the Framework 8.0 as an option in target platform for an existing C# dll project.
dotnet --info
.NET SDK:
 Version:           8.0.301
OS runtime:
 OS Name:     Windows
 OS Version:  10.0.22631
.NET SDKs installed:
  2.1.526 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
  3.1.426 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
  5.0.302 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
  8.0.300 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
  8.0.301 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
.NET runtimes installed:
  ... old versions starting with 2.1.30
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 8.0.5 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 8.0.6 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 8.0.5 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 8.0.6 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
  Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App 8.0.5 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App]
  Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App 8.0.6 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App]
Environment variables:
  Not set
global.json file:
  Not found


There's no .NET Framework 8. .NET 5 and later are .NET Core versions. If you filter project templates by .NET Framework you won't see the .NET (Core) templates

for an existing C# dll project. what kind of project is this and what's the current target version? Is it .NET Framework, .NET Standard or .NET (Core)? You can't switch a .NET Framework project to a .NET Core version just by changing the target. There's a migration tool but there may be some breaking changes too. Check the .NET Framework to .NET porting guidance. You can run the Upgrade assistant to see what needs to be changed

It is a .NET Framework.
When I create a new .NET (Core), then the 8.0 Framework will be shown.
Will try to change to a Core project and hope that the target Environement AutoCAD 2025 will support that kind of DLL.
@PanagiotisKanavos thx fot the hint

There's no .NET Framework 8. You can't use a .NET Core library in an application running on .NET Framework. Either target 4.8 or, if you need to share the library between .NET Framework and .NET Core projects, target .NET Standard 2.0
